# Angular: removing ng-hide/show for print version of the page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've got a webpage written in Angular that displays a lot of JSON data pulled from a server. To make it easier for the user to find the interesting data, we're putting everything into tables that are hidden by default (using `ng-hide` and `ng-show`).

When it comes to printing, though, we want everything to be immediately visible. Therefore everything must be expanded from the start - is there a way to do so? Can I somehow force the HTML to ignore the `ng-show` directives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with css media query, try

```
@media print {
   .ng-hide {
     display: block !important;
   }
}
```

Comment: edit: nevermind, I'm a dum-dum. It works perfectly, thank you :)